# Issues with strptime()

Tags: c, struct, strptime, tm

I am using the function `strptime()` to go from a string to a `struct tm`.  However, when I check the fields, there are a few that are not filled.  So I checked the man pages but it seems like I am doing the correct thing so now I am at a loss for what is going wrong.

sample input string:

```
Wed, 19 Oct 2005 10:59:00 GMT
```

strptime function:

```
if(strptime(date, "%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z", &time) != NULL)
```

It is my understanding that %a is for the day of the week, %d is for the day of the month, %b is for the month, %Y is for the year, %T is for HH:MM:SS and %Z is for GMT.

output of `tm struct`

```
year: 32767; month: 866041216; day: 0;
hour: 3; minute: 0; second: 37941328
```

code producing output:

```
printf("year: %d; month: %d; day: %d;\n",
        time.tm_year, time.tm_mon, time.tm_mday);
printf("hour: %d; minute: %d; second: %d\n",
        time.tm_hour, time.tm_min, time.tm_sec);
printf("week day: %d; year day: %d\n", time.tm_wday, time.tm_yday);
```

Any push in the right direction would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize `time` before calling `strptime`, typically like this:

```
memset(&time, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
```

Quoting the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strptime.3.html):

> In principle, this function does not initialize tm but only stores the
>   values specified.  This means that tm should be initialized before the
>   call.  Details differ a bit between different UNIX systems.  The glibc
>   implementation does not touch those fields which are not explicitly
>   specified, except that it recomputes the tm_wday and tm_yday field if
>   any of the year, month, or day elements changed.